# create a dataframe from the string pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subprocess

I am creating a program to list out the ip address and users connected in the LAN. I done by  getting the data by using nmap. Next i want to change the result data to a certain data frame using pandas or any other way. How to do it.

Here's the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import re

def ipget():
    i = 'nmap -sP 192.168.1.*'
    output = subprocess.getoutput(i)
    a = str(output).replace("Nmap","").replace("Starting  7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at","").replace("scan report for","").replace("Host is up","").replace("latency","").replace("done: 256 IP addresses ","")
    data = re.sub(r"(\(.*?\)\.)", "", a)
    print(data)
#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['User', 'IP_Address']) 

#print (df) 
ipget()
```

the output stored in data and it is a string:

```sh
2019-05-21 18:19 IST 
android-eb20919729f10e96 (192.168.1.8)

smackcoders (192.168.1.9)

princes-mbp (192.168.1.10)

shiv-mbp (192.168.1.15)

(4 hosts up) scanned in 18.35 seconds
```

Required output to be created in dataframe:

```sh
User                            IP_Address
android-eb20919729f10e96        192.168.1.8
smackcoders                     192.168.1.9
princes-mbp                     192.168.1.10
shiv-mbp                        192.168.1.15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying you have text:

```
2019-05-21 18:19 IST 
android-eb20919729f10e96 (192.168.1.8)

smackcoders (192.168.1.9)

princes-mbp (192.168.1.10)

shiv-mbp (192.168.1.15)

(4 hosts up) scanned in 18.35 seconds
```

Use regex to find the data you need:

```
>>> ms = re.findall(r'\n([^\s]*)\s+\((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\)', text)
>>> ms

[('android-eb20919729f10e96', '192.168.1.8'),
 ('smackcoders', '192.168.1.9'),
 ('princes-mbp', '192.168.1.10'),
 ('shiv-mbp', '192.168.1.15')]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(ms, columns=['User', 'IP_Address'])
```

---

Comparison to other answers:

1. Regex is short.
2. Regex only runs though your text *once*.

`str.replace` runs once per call so the regex solution can gain huge efficiency for long logs.

Answer (score 3):

Use StringIO

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
a="""
android-eb20919729f10e96 (192.168.1.8)

smackcoders (192.168.1.9)

princes-mbp (192.168.1.10)

shiv-mbp (192.168.1.15)"""

TESTDATA = StringIO(a)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=" ",names=['User','IP_Address'])
```

Add below line to remove `(` and `)`

```
import re
df.IP_Address = df.IP_Address.map(lambda x:re.sub('\(|\)',"",x))
```

Comment: However, this does include the parenthesis in IP.

Comment: @knh190 was still editing the post. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your string is named `s` the following code does what you want:

```
line_list = []

# iterate over each line
for line in s.split("\n"):
    #remove empty lines
    if line == '':
        continue

    #replace ( and ) with empty strings 
    line = line.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")

    line_list.append(line)

# remove first and last line
line_list = line_list[1:-1]

array = []
# split lines by " "
for line in line_list:
    array.append(line.split(" "))

# create dataframe
pd.DataFrame(array, columns = ["User", "IP_Adress"])
```

Using listcomprehension you can do the same as a oneliner:

```
pd.DataFrame([line.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(" ") for line in s.split("\n") if line != ""][1:-1], columns = ["User", "IP_Adress"])
```

Comment: There's definitely no need for multiple lines. One line regex is enough and more efficient.

Comment: I got it as a oneliner ;). Still your solution is way more elegant! +1 for your answer.

Comment: Upvoted but had to say that `str.replace` runs though whole text once per call while regex takes care of result in one run.